# Java generics are not making sense

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have a class `Teacher` and a class `Class`. Both extend the Class `Main`.

```
static void load() {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
        ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Main>> objects = 
                               ((ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Main>>) in.readObject();
        teachers = objects.get(0);
        classes = objects.get(1);
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`teachers` is an `ArrayList<Teacher>` and `classes` is an `ArrayList<Class>`. I get an error when trying to assign both ArrayLists their values. In my save method I write an `ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Main>>` to the file, so I am sure that the data type is correct. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Incompatible types: Required ArrayList<Teacher>, found ArrayList<capture<? extends Main>>

Comment: @CollinAlpert then you should try to cast the `objects.get(x)` to `ArrayList<Teacher>` and `ArrayList<Class>`

Comment: @CollinAlpert Yes, I deleted that comment. I read the question again and saw that.

Comment: @TomK That does work, yes, but I'm still wondering why my approach doesn't work.

Comment: @CollinAlpert the `objects.get()` method has the return type `ArrayList<? extends Main>` thus java cant be sure if thats actually a `ArrayList<Teacher>` or a `ArrayList<Class>` or whatever else

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated: don't use inheritance because it looks convenient. You use inheritance because A **is a** B. So, Teacher and Class, they are **both** Mains? You should step back and look carefully at your OO modelling here. And, side note: there is already a class java.lang.Class. It is really a bad idea to call your own class Class, too!

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the tips! My class isn't really called `Class`. It's in German but for Stackoverflow I just translated it.

Comment: Which makes sense ;-) ... but hint: even when translating, avoid re-using names that have such a "predefined" meaning. Und selbst im Deutschen ist ein Lehrer kein Haupt, und Klasse ist auch kein Haupt ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat Ich werd' in Zukunft dran denken!

Comment: All fine. And talking about the future ... keep [mcve] in mind. But still, nice question.